# When I try to send email in Samsung Galaxy S10 the app crashes

Tags: java, android-studio, email

The user will register their new account. Before getting to the registration page they have to accept a consent form. After accepting the consent form a pop up message will require them to enter their email address for them to receive an email. When I press 'send' insted of sending the email and loading the next activity, the app crashes. In the emulators, as well as my Huawei Mate 10 Pro device the app works perfectly fine. When I run the app in Samsung Galaxy S10 it crashes.

Here is the Consent Activity

```
    package com.example.sport_screen.Consent_Activities;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.sport_screen.Database.DBHelper;
import com.example.sport_screen.For_Admin.AdminActivity;
import com.example.sport_screen.LoginActivity;
import com.example.sport_screen.R;
import com.example.sport_screen.RegisterActivity;
import com.example.sport_screen.Utils;
import com.example.sport_screen.WelcomeActivity;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView;

public class Temp_InformedConsent_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    NeumorphCardView denyBtn, consentBtn;
    TextView par1, par2, par3, par4, par6, sendBtn;
    Dialog dialog;
    EditText enterEmail, messageEmail;
    String valid_email, msg;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    private long backPressedTime;
    private Toast backToast;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (backPressedTime + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            backToast.cancel();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            msg = "Press back again to logout";
            backToast = toastLayout();
            backToast.show();
        }

        backPressedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_informed_consent);
        DBHelper database = new DBHelper(this);
        Utils.blackIconStatusBar(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.this, R.color.light_Background);

        dialog = new Dialog(this);

        par1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.par1);
        par2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.par2);
        par3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.par3);
        par4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.par4);
        par6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.par6);

        consentBtn = (NeumorphCardView) findViewById(R.id.consentBtn);
        denyBtn = (NeumorphCardView) findViewById(R.id.denyBtn);

        String p1 = "Consent\nTo voluntarily engage on an acceptable plan of personal fitness training. Follow the exact instructions regarding exercise, stress management and other health and fitness regarded programs. I have informed the trainer of any medication prescribed to me. I will allow a personal fitness trainer to periodically monitor performance and measure pulse, blood pressure etc. Allow physical touching and body positioning as required by the performed exercises.";
        String p2 = "Risks (I have be informed of possible..)\nAbnormal blood pressure, fainting, dizziness, disorders of heart rhythm; and very rare cases: heart attack, stroke or even death. furthermore possible bodily injury, to muscles, ligaments, tendons and joints of the body.\nI fully understand the risks but knowing them it is my desire to participate.";
        String p3 = "Benefits\nUnderstand that if I closely follow the program instructions, that I will likely improve my exercise capacity and fitness level after a period of 3-6 months.";
        String p4 = "Confidentiality\nAny obtained information will be treated in confidentiality, not revealed to any person. Any unidentifiable information might be used for research purposes. Any information obtained will be used by the program staff to evaluate my exercise status or needs.";
        String p6 = "By pressing YES, you agree to download the FULL version of Informed Consent Form, Sign It and provide it to the administration for verification later on.";

        SpannableString s1 = new SpannableString(p1);
        SpannableString s2 = new SpannableString(p2);
        SpannableString s3 = new SpannableString(p3);
        SpannableString s4 = new SpannableString(p4);
        SpannableString s6 = new SpannableString(p6);

        ForegroundColorSpan fcsRed = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
        ForegroundColorSpan fcsBlack = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK);
        UnderlineSpan underlineSpan = new UnderlineSpan();
        StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        StyleSpan boldSpan2 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);

        s1.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s1.setSpan(fcsBlack, 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s2.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s2.setSpan(fcsBlack, 0, 40, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s3.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s3.setSpan(fcsBlack, 0, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s4.setSpan(boldSpan, 0, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s4.setSpan(fcsBlack, 0, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s6.setSpan(fcsRed, 0, 153, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s6.setSpan(boldSpan, 11, 15, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s6.setSpan(boldSpan2, 81, 89, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        s6.setSpan(underlineSpan, 29, 55, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        par1.setText(s1);
        par2.setText(s2);
        par3.setText(s3);
        par4.setText(s4);
        par6.setText(s6);

        consentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.privacy_cons_dialog);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

                //progressBar = dialog.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                sendBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
                enterEmail = dialog.findViewById(R.id.emailPrivacyCons);
                messageEmail = dialog.findViewById(R.id.messagePrivacyCons);

                sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if (enterEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty() || isEmailValid(enterEmail.getText().toString()) == false)
                        {
                            enterEmail.setError("Please enter a valid Email");
                            enterEmail.requestFocus();
                            valid_email = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            final String usernameNoReply = "noreply.sportscreen@gmail.com";
                            final String usernameSportScreen = "sportscreen.app@gmail.com";
                            final String password = "SportScreenApp123";

                            messageEmail.setText("Hello,\n\nClick the following link to Download the Full Version of Informed Consent form.\n\nhttps://www.exerciseismedicine.org/assets/page_documents/EIM%20informed%20consent.pdf" +
                                    "\n\nPlease read this Informed Consent form carefully, and sign it freely and voluntary. " +
                                    "\nIf you give your consent, please provide the form (filled) printed to the Administration and via email for verification." +
                                    "\n\nTo send via email, please reply/send to this email.\nSportScreen.");
                            String messageToSend = messageEmail.getText().toString();

                            Properties props = System.getProperties();
                            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
                            Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                                    new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                                        @Override
                                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                            return new PasswordAuthentication(usernameSportScreen, password);
                                        }
                                    });
                            try {
                                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(usernameSportScreen));
                                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(enterEmail.getText().toString()));
                                message.setSubject("Informed Consent PDF File Link");
                                message.setText(messageToSend);
                                Transport.send(message);
                                msg ="Email Send Successfully!";

                                toastLayout();

                                dialog.dismiss();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                                finish();
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }catch (MessagingException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }



                        }
                    }
                });
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                dialog.show();

                //String cons = "YES";
                //database.insertToTempInformed("", cons);

            }
        });

        denyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.temp_dialog_layout);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        finish();
                    }
                }, 4000);

            }
        });
    }



    boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {
        return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private Toast toastLayout()
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        View view = toast.getView();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast);
        view.getBackground().setAlpha(180);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

        text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM,0,0);
        toast.setMargin(0, 0.04f);
        toast.show();
        return toast;
    }

}
```

And here is part of the error I am getting (Due to characters limitation I cannot copy the whole error)

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.sport_screen, PID: 24223
        java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
        534-5.7.14 kzU3_9rFrArcGA_N2tY05H7mw1IfxTrv04q3e4VFaEEk-y2LT0fdBPNDDg4XPSes6Z5PY
        534-5.7.14 3t1BT-tlgZNY2GMtVy33-K35Hr3w5B_6jM4KOOn0L0JiyER3J-XAWaJVIQiMpxx8>
        534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
        534-5.7.14  Learn more at
        534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d27-20020adfa41b000000b0020d012692dbsm114594wra.18 - gsmtp

        at com.example.sport_screen.Consent_Activities.Temp_InformedConsent_Activity$1$1.onClick(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.java:197)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
        at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
        Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbt
        534-5.7.14 kzU3_9rFrArcGA_N2tY05H7mw1IfxTrv04q3e4VFaEEk-y2LT0fdBPNDDg4XPSes6Z5PY
        534-5.7.14 3t1BT-tlgZNY2GMtVy33-K35Hr3w5B_6jM4KOOn0L0JiyER3J-XAWaJVIQiMpxx8>
        534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again.
        534-5.7.14  Learn more at
        534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 d27-20020adfa41b000000b0020d012692dbsm114594wra.18 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:947)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:858)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:762)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
        at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
        at com.example.sport_screen.Consent_Activities.Temp_InformedConsent_Activity$1$1.onClick(Temp_InformedConsent_Activity.java:185)
        ... 13 more
        I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24223 SIG: 9
```

Comment: You want to send a mail via googles servers with simple smtp authentication from many different devices? I don't think that's really a good approach and google would probably block logins to that account pretty fast. If you want to stick with this approach you probably need another mail provider.

Comment: I am a little unfamiliar with this to be honest. This is the first time I attempted to apply the send email functionality in an app. Could you suggest something?

Comment: Modern email can be pretty complicated with all the spam prevention. Apps that send you emails normally have the App communicate with a server of their own and then that server triggers another server to send an email. There's services like sendgrid, mailchimp, etc. that can take over for the sending of the emails. For the server-side, if you don't want to host your own server you can use something like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-firestore-send-email). You don't need all of these services, but building something yourself if probably going to be harder.

Comment: You could get a cheap domain with a simple smtp email service, that doesn't do all the security checks that google does. But if you store the email user/password inside your app then spammers are probably going to hijack them in no time.